# Adding state to HXT parsing

Tags: haskell, hxt

I'm trying to write an arrow that will generate numbered elements from an XML parse with HXT.  It seems like it should be done with a state arrow, like the State monad, but all the examples I can find in the HXT package and the methods to access the state ([XmlState](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hxt/9.0.1/doc/html/Text-XML-HXT-Arrow-XmlState.html)) use the IOStateArrow and I would much rather keep it pure to simplify the testing process, with the StateArrow.  Do such variants exist?  If not, how would I add state to an HXT parse without having to resort to running the Arrow in IO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ArrowState](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hxt/9.0.1/doc/html/Control-Arrow-ArrowState.html#t%3aArrowState) instance of [SLA](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hxt/9.0.1/doc/html/Control-Arrow-StateListArrow.html#t%3aSLA) for that.
An example: let assume we need to concatenate all the second-level text elements.

```
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> fst $ runSLA (xread >>> getChildren >>> getChildren >>> isText >>> getText >>> changeState (++)) "" "<xml><item>a</item><item>b</item></xml>" 
"ab"
```

Note, that you can't use `IO` inside the `SLA` since in doesn't have `ArrowIO` instance.

Hope, it is what you need.